# What is valid and what is invalid to send to Elasticsearch Bulk?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a comprehensive list of what is valid and what is invalid when sending a bulk payload to ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk endpoint is a indexing endpoint. So at a highlevel you can only send indexing requests to that endpoint.

Since its bulk, a valid request is designed around multiple doc and how they are delimited. e.g. if you can not using a ES client then  you will need to have payload formatted as ndjson (new delimited json) and last doc should end in a new line as well. Better to use a client since a client will do this all for you.

Apart from syntax of payload data you can target a index , a type etc in URL. 
You can also send some other param like "wait_for_completion", "retry_on_conflict" etc. These are parameter which will control how each requests will behave.

Needless to say but best would be to read up the doc:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html